# Removing a column from result set in Groovy Sql rows

Tags: groovy

I have a query where I need to retrieve a column which I need only temporarily because I need to pass it in the parameter for a where clause, how can I remove this column and its value from my result set after it served that purpose. Hopefully the code will show what I mean...

```
def empQuery = "select id, name, address from Employee"
def retObj = [:]
def sql = new Sql(datasource)

retObj = sql.rows(empQuery.toString())

retObj.each { 
   def addressQuery = "select street from Address where employe_id = ${it['id']} 
   // at this point I want to remove 'id:n' from the result set hash map aka 'it'
}
```

Because later on I am displaying that result set on a page for the user, and the ID field is not relevant.

So can you please show the Groovy code to remove a column and its value from the rows data structure returned from sql.rows?

Comment: What ways have you tried to remove it so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html
It looks like you can do something line:
retObj.each { it.remove('id')} 
However I haven't tried it....